# ecs/fargate logging from stdout (equivalent of -t option in docker)

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a program that I'd like to run in Docker that outputs a dot every 3 seconds to stdout. Locally, if I run this I don't see the logs:

docker build .
docker start

whereas if I do this, I see the logs:

docker build .
docker start -t

Now, how would i get the logs when deploying to amazon fargate? I've tried a number of things but it seems stdout stream isn't being saved to the cloudwatch.

Comment: Can you please share your ECS Service Task Definition details?. Have you checked the role assigned has necessary permissions to write to CW?.

Answer (score 1):

To get stdout logs in Cloudwatch you just need to specify the log driver in your ECS Task definition as awslogs.

Find more info here: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/awslogs/

and here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_cloudwatch_logs.html